# Why does my bash script not print out an echo statement?

Tags: bash

I have a function that reads the width and checks for any characters, it doesn't print out the error I want it to

```
echo "Enter width"
read width

v='^[0-9]+$'

function width() {
if ! [[ $width =~ $v ]] ; then
   echo "ERROR - INPUT A NUMBER" >&2; return width
fi
}
```

Comment: Do you ever run the `which` function, or just define it? Also, `return width` won't work -- functions do not return data, they return integer status codes between 0 and 255 (0=success, anything else=failure). BTW, [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I was under the assumption that `return width` was running the function again. Is there a way I can call the function if I cannot use `return width`

Comment: Just call it recursively: `width`. That said, the function should take an argument, not look at a global variable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to. If you want to keep reading the input until some condition is met, you should do something like:

```
v='^[0-9]+$' 

read -p "Enter width: " width
while [[ ! $width =~ $v ]]
do
  read -p "Enter width: " width
done
```

Comment: You can put the `read` in the condition and use an empty body to avoid repeating yourself: `while read -p "..." width && [[ ! $width =~ $v ]]; do :; done`.

Comment: @chepner I learned something new. Which is why answering questions can help you back. Thanks.

Comment: @chepner Can you show me an example of what you mean? appreciate it

Comment: @Dev It's exactly what he posted.

Comment: @maroun ah it makes a lot more sense, can you explain to me what `:;` does, its the only bit I dont understand

Comment: @Dev it's just an empty body.

Comment: @Dev `:` is a sort of null or placeholder command; it's a command as far as shell syntax is concerned, but it doesn't actually do anything (well, it does set an exit status of 0, because it does nothing *successfully*). In this case, it's being used as the body of the loop, because a completely empty loop body would be a syntax error.